# Sonar plugin query the database

Tags: database, plugins, sonarqube

I'm developing a sonar plugin and I have some questions about it.
My plugin need to retrieve data from the database to manipulate them and display them in a page.

Currently, my plugin is querying the database using JDBC driver but I think it will be a problem in production.
So I want to find a method to connect and query the database (just select query) from my plugin using an API, or an sonar object...

I know there are some WebService, but they don't give me all information that I need, so I have to make queries by myself.

My plugin is for Sonarqube 4.1.

I hope my explication was clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

I have a Class who retrieve the databaseSessionFactory in the constructor. I read somewhere that Sonar uses dependency injection by constructor.

```
    public class MyClass implements WebService{

        privateDatabaseSessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public MyClass(DatabaseSessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }
    }
```

And after, in this Class, I can use SessionFactory variable to Query the database:

```
        DatabaseSession s = sessionFactory.getSession();
        String sqlQuery ="SELECT d.data FROM " + SnapshotSource.class.getName() + " d "
                    + "WHERE d.id = :Id";
        Query query = s.createQuery(sqlQuery);

        query.setParameter("Id", 1);

        List<String> queryResult = (List<String>) query.getResultList();
        //queryResult.get(0) contains the source
```

In this example, I get the first snapshot source in the database.
I hope it's a good solution and it can help anybody.

Answer (score 0):

You shall not query the SonarQube database directly. The DB schema is private and may change without notice, plus you risk to generate side effects to SonarQube itself.

If you need to read some stuff from the DB you should use the Web Services API that allows to query most of the "objects" manipulated by SonarQube.
In such case this is not really a plugin, just an external client application.

You also have the alternative to use the SonarQube Java APIs if you want to write a SonarQube plugin that displays something in the SonarQube UI (like a custom widget).

Comment: Yes I tried this method:  "Sonar sonar = Sonar.create("http://localhost:9000", "login", "password");"   in a webService created in Java but I have an error : "ERROR [rails]  
Java::JavaLang::NoClassDefFoundError (org/sonar/wsclient/Sonar)"